# ASP.NET Single Sign On

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, asp.net-identity

We have two servers that run on the same machine under the same domain.

Both written in ASP.NET and uses the Identity framework.

I need to implement Single Sign-On (and single sign out) between them.

Actual sign-in is done in AJAX (I *POST* the username and password, the server authenticate the user and sets the session, then sends the redirect data URL to the client).

I found overwhelming amount of information about OWIN, the Identity framework, Claims, etc.

I found tutorials explaining how to create projects using just about any modal dialog and any Wizard there is in Visual Studio, which I tried to understand but really is useless to me, as I already have authentication system up and running.

I even found some demos claiming to implement SSO in all kinds of ways, and some Stackoverflow questions that said to simply put this and that values in the *web.config* and you're done, which seemed strange to me and I figured out I'm missing some basic understanding of how it works.

Still, I can't understand how SSO works in ASP.NET Identity.

**Can someone please explain it to me in a simple manner, or refer me to some kind of such explanation?**

Again: I have two authentication systems up and running. What code and/or configuration changes I need to make to get Single Sign-On working?

Comment: What authentication system are you using?

Comment: As I said, the Identity Framework, unless you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want them to share authentication, they need to be working on the same user store. In other words, you should factor out the Identity initialization code (`ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationDbContext`, `ApplicationUserManager`, and `ApplicationSignInManager`) into a class library that both applications share. Trying to mantain and share two separate databases with user data is going to be an impossible and insurmountable task.

Then, you need only ensure that both applications utilize the same machine key. The auth cookie is encrypted, and since the encryption is based on the machine key, both applications need to use the same key to encrypt/decrypt that cookie.

Since you've already stated that they will both be hosted on the same domain, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Well, the users database is shared already. So if I understand you correctly it should just work. I'm no longer at work and can't check it, but I think that's not the case.

Comment: Because you're not sharing the machine key. By default, a unique key is generated and used by each application. You need to remove that variability and specify the same machine key in the Web.config of each site.

Comment: I tried and it did work locally, but I have the concern now - will it also work when behind a load balancer?

Comment: I don't see why not. The whole point is to get the two applications on the same playing field. You have to do this as well if you just want to use web workers in IIS. A load balancer is pretty much the same thing, just spread across multiple servers.

Comment: Another follow-up question, if you may - should it also work if the servers run on different sub-domains under the same domain?

Comment: It will as long as the cookie is set on the wildcard. In other words, if you set the cookie on `sub1.domain.com`, it will only be available to `sub1.domain.com`, but if it's set on `.domain.com` then it will be fed to both.